# MySQL will not insert transaction

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, transactions

I am trying to get a transaction to execute. I can get a normal query to execute but not a transaction.

These are my queries:

```
$queries[] = "START TRANSACTION";
$queries[] = "INSERT INTO `customer_register` ( `c_email`,`web_customer_id`,`c_realname`,`c_password` ) VALUES ( 'support@mail.com','1','Name','test' )";
$queries[] = "COMMIT";
```

Method to commit the transaction:

```
private function commit_transaction($queries) {

    foreach($queries as $query) {
        if($this -> db -> blank_query($query)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $this -> db -> blank_query("ROLLBACK");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Method to execute the query:

```
public function blank_query($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this -> link, $query);
    if(mysqli_errno($this -> link)) {
        if(!empty($this -> note)) {
            $this -> note -> pushNotification('error', "Error executing blank query");
        }
        $this -> write_to_log('Error: ' . mysqli_error($this -> link) . ' Query: ' . $query);
        return false;
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

If I just do:

```
$this -> db -> blank_query("INSERT INTO `customer_register` ( `c_email`,`web_customer_id`,`c_realname`,`c_password` ) VALUES ( 'support@mail.com','1','Name','test' )");
```

Everything goes great, but this could be sumitting 10, 20 or 100 queries on page load so I need to to be fast.
The transaction also commits fine in phpmyadmin:

```
"START TRANSACTION; INSERT INTO `customer_register` ( `c_email`,`web_customer_id`,`c_realname`,`c_password` ) VALUES ( 'support@mail.com','1','Name','test' ); COMMIT;"
```

Comment: It could be quite possible that it's hitting the `ROLLBACK`. Try chucking a few `echo`'s around the place, that'll show you where the problem lies.

Comment: Aye, I thought that also. Everything I can see returns true I think it may not be the functions presented here. Cheers for your valid input tho bud.